# Conditional Statements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the jQuery code below and currently it has a `Min Rent` and `Max Rent` field. Right now when a value is entered is says `$val1 to $0` even if a value is not entered in the `Max Rent` field. What I am trying to accomplish is if a value is entered in both fields for it to say `$val1 to $val2`. Otherwise I just want it to display the one value. I tried to do this with a conditional statement, but my jQuery is not very strong and not sure where I am going wrong.

jQuery:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_min_price").keyup(modPrice);
  $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_max_price").keyup(modPrice);
});

$("[data-toggle='popover']").on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
modPrice();
});
modPrice();

function modPrice() {
  if ($("#listing-price-selector") && $("#listing-price-selector").next()) {
    var mn = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_min_price").val();
    var mx = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_max_price").val();
    if (mn || mx) {
      mn = (mn == "") ? 0 : mn;
      mx = (mx == "") ? 0 : mx;
      $("#priceBox").val(mn + " to " + mx);
      if ($("#listing_search_form_max_price").length > 0) {
        $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn + " to $" + mx);
      else
        $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
    <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-price-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">Price Range <span class="caret"></span></a>
</div>

<div id="listing-price-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <%= f.text_field :min_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Min Rent", data: { "binding-name" => "min-price" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <%= f.text_field :max_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Max Rent", data: { "binding-name" => "max-price" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does your code really say `if ($(# listing_search_form_max_price).length > 0) {`? Shouldn't there be some quotes in there?

Comment: @muistooshort Whoops. There should be quotes in there, but that still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Hi could you please point me which `if` is causing the issue here ? I'm still trying to workout the question ..`$val1 to $0`.. So you are able to get `mn` and `mx` values and you are trying to fix the `if (mn || mx) {` ? *Otherwise I just want it to display the one value* where ?

Comment: @Searching Apologies. It is the 3rd and final if statement. if ($("#listing_search_form_max_price").length > 0) {
        $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn + " to $" + mx);
      else
        $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn);
      }

Comment: Hey..No probs. So that means if they have entered a value in max_price `#listing_search_form_max_price`, then display `$("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn + " to $" + mx);` else the other. Correct ? The way you do this `$("#listing_search_form_max_price").length` is to check if a there is anything in the input ? Why not use `$("#listing_search_form_max_price").val()` ?

Comment: @Searching Would you mind showing me? My jQuery is horrible.

Comment: Actually that was it `if(parseFloat($("#listing_search_form_max_price").val()) > 0){ ... }`. But are you able to share what  `alert($("#listing_search_form_max_price").val())` returns ?

Comment: @Searching It broke my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if my comment helped. So I'm posting this. 
Provided that this is where, your issue is, this type of check here is not recommended. For all you know they can input "abcd"

```
if ($("#listing_search_form_max_price").length > 0) {
    $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn + " to $" + mx);
  else
    $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn);
  }
```

You can try this

```
function modPrice() {
    if ($("#listing-price-selector") && $("#listing-price-selector").next()) {
        var mn = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_min_price").val();
        var mx = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_max_price").val();
        if (mn || mx) {
            mn = (mn == "") ? 0 : mn;
            mx = (mx == "") ? 0 : mx;
            $("#priceBox").val(mn + " to " + mx);
            if (parseFloat($("#listing_search_form_max_price").val()) > 0) {
                $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn + " to $" + mx);
            } else {
                $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn);
            } //END listing_search_form_max_price
        } //END mn || mx
    } //END listing-price-selector
}
```

Let us know.

Comment: That broke my Price Range dropdown.

Comment: Hmm.. but this is still 98% of what was already there, the only change here is the if clause..

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart I've update the answer checked a few closing `}` .

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart No problemo.. on a side note if you are comparing numbers you might want to check if it's a `number` and then use them. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp . Happy coding.